# HtmlAgilityPack causes object not matched exception and crash of app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, html-agility-pack

When running the following code I'm getting a "Object of type 'NInterpret.InterpretedObject' doesnt't match target type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[NInterpretedObject]'" error from Xamarin Live Player:

```
var html = @"randomURL.html";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var page = web.Load(html);
```

The App also crashes when I install the .apk directly on my phone, it works just fine in the Android emulator though.
The error seems to be in the last line, but I haven't found a workaround or other methods that work with Xamarin.

Comment: The error message says that it was expecting a collection, but you provided it with a single item, not a collection.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure how to fix that, though, since it's running just fine in the Android emulator.

Comment: if it's trying to download content from an external URL, do you have INTERNET permissions enabled?